# Deploy application using installshield

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, visual-studio-2012, deployment

I have developed an **WPF** application using **.Net 4.0 framework**. I have installed **SQL 2012 Express edition** on my machine .
My application performs basic CRUD operations on this database using appropriate connectionstring. **I am very new to deployment**. so my question is How can I deploy my mdf files at the client end ? I cannot install ~130MB of software at client end just for my 4MB of mdf files it doesn't make sense. Also while deploying project I saw this pre-requisites screen

[image]

My questions are:

1. (I think if i check `SQL Server 2008 Express SP1` it will download it at client end) But I have SQL 2012 Express Edition Installed so how can I go with it ?.
2. Also is it possible If I give client seperate exe of my SQL 2012 Express edition ? (There is no need for management studio at clientside.so what should be given to client so it that installs only those software which are required to run **.mdf** file )

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question,
1. You will require a .prq file for SQL server 2012. Either you can create it or you can download it from web. You can add/edit '.prq' file from 'Redistributable' section.
For your second question, 
2. You can pass the setup of aql 2012 express to your client with specific instructions to only install server and not the management studio.

Answer (score -1):

You need [SQL Server Compact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/ff687142.aspx) most probably